# What's the point to have a UNK token for out of vocabulary words during decoding?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, neural-network, machine-translation, oov

First of all, I know this question is kind of off-topic, but I have already tried to ask elsewhere but got no response.

Adding a `UNK` token to the vocabulary is a conventional way to handle oov words in tasks of NLP. It is totally understandable to have it for encoding, but what's the point to have it for decoding? I mean you would never expect your decoder to generate a `UNK` token during prediction, right?

Comment: After several years, theres some tricks to handle OOV or UNK. Take a look at https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-byte-fallback-work-and-affect-vocab-size-in-bpe/64634 and https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/main/tokenizers/src/decoders/byte_fallback.rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you preprocess your training data, you might need the `UNK` during training. Even if you use BPE or other subword segmentation, OOV can appear in the training data, usually some weird UTF-8 stuff, fragments of alphabets, you are not interested in at all, etc.

For example, if you take WMT training data for English-German translation, do BPE and take the vocabulary, you vocabulary will contain thousands of Chinese characters that occur exactly once in the training data. Even if you keep them in the vocabulary, the model has no chance to learn anything about them, not even to copy them. It makes sense to represent them as `UNK`s.

Of course, what you usually do at the inference time is that you prevent the model predict `UNK` tokens, `UNK` is always incorrect.

Comment: So what does mapping those weird tokens to UNK buy us? It looks to me like this can help us to reduce some cost during decoding by without wasting time on computing logits for those weird tokens. Am I right about it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It just saves a lot of hassle you would otherwise go through while preparing the training data.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it one time in the following situation:

I had a preprocessed word2vec(glove.6b.50d.txt) and I was outputting an embedded vector, in order to transform it into a word I used cosine similarity based on all vectors in the word2vec if the most similar vector was the  I would output it.

Maybe I'm just guessing it here, but what I think might happen under the hoods is that it predicts based on previous words(e.g. it predicts the word that appeared 3 iterations ago) and if that word is  the neural net outputs it.